# Cleaning up BigQueryInputFormat temp files

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I am using the BigQueryInputFormat in a spark job, to load data directly from Bigquery into an RDD.  The documentation for this states that you should cleanup temporary files using the command:

BigQueryInputFormat.cleanupJob(job)

However from a Spark job, how can I do that, when "job" is a hadoop job?

Thank,
Luke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, you can set a custom temp path that is unique to your spark job, and delete that path at the end of the job:

```
hadoopConf.set(BigQueryConfiguration.TEMP_GCS_PATH_KEY, "gs://mybucket/hadoop/tmp/1234")

...

FileSystem.get(new Configuration()).delete(new Path(hadoopConf.get(BigQueryConfiguration.TEMP_GCS_PATH_KEY)), true)
```